# how can we make synced carousel position bottom to right in owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Hi i want to pick the pagination on bottom to right side and i have tried so many ways but this thumbnail not working in the right position , is there any possibility to do this ?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
     
      var sync1 = $("#sync1");
      var sync2 = $("#sync2");
     
      sync1.owlCarousel({
        singleItem : true,
        slideSpeed : 1000,
        navigation: true,
        pagination:false,
        afterAction : syncPosition,
        responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
      });
     
      sync2.owlCarousel({
        items : 15,
        itemsDesktop      : [1199,10],
        itemsDesktopSmall     : [979,10],
        itemsTablet       : [768,8],
        itemsMobile       : [479,4],
        pagination:false,
        responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
        afterInit : function(el){
          el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
        }
      });
     
      function syncPosition(el){
        var current = this.currentItem;
        $("#sync2")
          .find(".owl-item")
          .removeClass("synced")
          .eq(current)
          .addClass("synced")
        if($("#sync2").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
          center(current)
        }
      }
     
      $("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
        sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
      });
     
      function center(number){
        var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
        var num = number;
        var found = false;
        for(var i in sync2visible){
          if(num === sync2visible[i]){
            var found = true;
          }
        }
     
        if(found===false){
          if(num>sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
            sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length+2)
          }else{
            if(num - 1 === -1){
              num = 0;
            }
            sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
          }
        } else if(num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
          sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1])
        } else if(num === sync2visible[0]){
          sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1)
        }
        
      }
     
    });
```

```css
#sync1 .item{
    background: #0c83e7;
    padding: 80px 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
#sync2 .item{
    background: #C9C9C9;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#sync2 .item h1{
  font-size: 18px;
}
#sync2 .synced .item{
  background: #0c83e7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>6</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>7</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>8</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>9</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>10</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>11</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>12</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>13</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>14</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>15</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>16</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>17</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>18</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>19</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>20</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>21</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>22</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>23</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>6</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>7</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>8</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>9</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>10</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>11</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>12</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>13</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>14</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>15</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>16</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>17</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>18</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>19</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>20</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>21</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>22</h1></div>
      <div class="item"><h1>23</h1></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your question is not quite clear. Please explain what you expect to achieve

Comment: sync1 is the main slider , sync 2 is thumbnail slider, like pager , i just want to put the thumbnail on right side of the slider